# How to change heading tag of page builder elements in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpbakery

I am using a WordPress theme named "Delaware" which utilizes WP Bakery as its page builder.

The issue with it is that some of their custom elements in WP Bakery don't offer the option to change the heading tag.

Is there any way I can change it by editing the core files or theme editor?

Here's what the inspect element shows:

```
<div class ="box-title"><h2>Chloe Smith</h2><div class="border"></div>
```

Or how can I locate the file from where it is coming so that I can edit it?

Domain name: aidenfinserv.com

[image: screenshot of webpage]

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to locate your file unless you give access to a developer. You probably need to make use of [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for one of the hooks using this code: https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/filters/wpb_widget_title/ which goes into your functions.php

I also have a vanilla JavaScript solution for you at the moment which I have tried. You can paste the JavaScript part in your Theme options custom JS or `script.js` file.

```js
const boxTitlesh2 = document.querySelectorAll(".box-title h2");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  boxTitlesh2.forEach((boxTitleh2) => {
    const boxTitleh3 = document.createElement("div"); // Replace with your custom element
    boxTitleh3.innerText = boxTitleh2.innerText; // You can replace it with your custom text.
    boxTitleh3.setAttribute("class","custom-heading"); // Better for styling purposes
    boxTitleh2.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', boxTitleh3);
    boxTitleh2.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="box-testi" style="">
  <div class="box-title">
    <h2>Prisha Matondkar</h2>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <p class="sub-title">Sydney, Australia</p><span class="dl-icon-quote svg-icon"></span></div>
  <p>Highest Quality Accounting Services, They'll Assign Dedicated Accountants to you unlike some other companies. And The Accountants were always cheerful to Listen to my queries. Will Prefer Aiden Finserv instead of hiring our own accounts team</p>
</div>


<div class="box-testi" style="">
  <div class="box-title">
    <h2>Chloe Smith</h2>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <p class="sub-title">Chicago, USA</p><span class="dl-icon-quote svg-icon"></span></div>
  <p>Aiden Finserv Client Dashboard for accounting services is one of the most unique things among any Accountant Firm. I can manage everything and its easier to have everything stacked up in one place. I have worked with 8+ Accountant firms and has never
    seen anything like this.</p>
</div>
```

**Live output:**

[image]